# Split Containers without too many HWNDs

Tags: winforms, splitter

I need to arrange a few of my controls using split containers such that one split container is nested inside another. I find that each instance of the `SplitContainer` class is itself a `Control` and comes with two instances of `SplitterPanel` which is a control too.

For example, in the following illustration, I am arranging just 3 of my controls (HWNDs 8, 9 and 5) using 2 `SplitContainer` instances but end up with a whole lot of additional HWNDs as a result of using `SplitContainer`.

[image: Split Container]
<sub>(source: [googlepages.com](http://agnel.kurian.googlepages.com/splitcontainer.PNG))</sub>

In addition to this, the child controls must use `Parent.Parent.Parent...` ad nauseum in order to reach their parent form (yes I can use `FindForm` instead). Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:** The splitter needs to be resizable

Answer (score 1):

You could use a TableLayoutPanel where you give the bottom control ColumnSpan of two.

You can do this in code with

```
this.tableLayoutPanel.SetColumnSpan(this.button1, 2);
```

Or use the properties window in the designer.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the splitter needs to be resizable as well.